# Get coordinates of a rotated point by openCV and python

Tags: python, image, opencv

I want to rotate an image without cropping by using cv2.getRotationMatrix2D and cv2.warpAffine. But how can I get the coordinate of a point (x,y) from the original image on the rotated image?

Comment: I think doing a matrix multiplication between your (x,y) and cv2.getRotationMatrix2D will result in the coordinate of (x,y) in new image?

Comment: use the same transformation you used in warpAffine, add a 0,0,1 row and transform the point with cv::perspectiveTransform, or just multiply the point in homogenous coordinates with the transfirmation (matrix multiplication)

Comment: rotation_matrix = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(image_center, (-1) * angle, 1.)
startpoint = np.asarray([[x1, y1]])
new_point = np.dot(startpoint, rotation_matrix)
so?

Comment: Get pyimagesearch's imutils. It has expanding rotation.

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/irmowan/Face-Recognition/blob/master/transform.py